# "File format is not supported" when trying to open a 2.72 .blend file

Tags: blend-files, versions, error

I was looking into **Sun Rays** done in **Compositor**, so I headed over to [this link](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.72/Compositing).

Neither of the two files hosted there (*Windows.blend* and *Sky.blend*) could be opened by my 2.78 version of **Blender**:

[image]
[image]

I have always been able to open older files, even much older files, so what is going on here and **why can't I open these files?**

Comment: Could not open any of the files either, but I didn't get any message like you did, it just failed silently, and ket the default scene open as if nothing happened. Not sure, might be a bug or corrupted files.

Comment: Both of them open perfectly in my system... (the one for the windows does not have the image packed into the file, so don't bother with that one...)

Comment: What are your system specs?

Comment: me too, both open normally on my 2.78a on w7x64

Comment: could they be incomplete/corrupted? windows.blend is 529.436 byte and sky.blend is 906.624 byte

Comment: I think you are saving the file from the links on the page you show. You need to open each page and then download the blend file from the second page.